# Colour conversion discrepancies between — and within — Adobe apps

Tags: adobe-indesign, color-conversion, adobe-acrobat, pantone, color-reproduction

I work a lot with brand colours specified as Pantones, but often printed as CMYK. Naturally, I want those conversions to be as accurate and as consistent as possible, and I keep my Adobe applications’ colour settings synchronised (via Bridge) to use the ‘Europe General Purpose’ preset.

### What I've checked:

Testing shows me that as long as the colour settings and document profiles all match between applications, Adobe InDesign and Adobe Illustrator will provide identical colour values when converting a Pantone swatch (chosen from the Pantone+ Solid Coated book, FWIW) to either RGB or CMYK values via the applications colour palette.

Pasting that derived RGB (or hex) value from either of those apps into Photoshop's colour picker also provides CMYK values that match the derived values from InDesign and Illustrator (though there is some rounding off of the numbers -- InDesign and Illustrator both provided converted CMYK values to 2 decimal places, whereas Photoshop deals in integers).

Everything seems to agree. That's good, right?

### Creating a test document

Now I create a document in InDesign (giving it a colour profile to match the working space) and in it create two squares of colour, one using a Pantone swatch and one using the converted CMYK equivalent of that same Pantone colour reference. I then export that document to PDF using InDesign’s native export (as opposed to using Distiller, which, if I'm honest, I never have time for in my workflow).

My export settings are very close to PDF/X-1a standard, the only real different being that compatibility is set to Acrobat 5 rather than 4. Compression and Printer mMarks are irrelevant for this test, and the Output settings are ‘Colour Conversion: Convert to Destination (Preserve Numbers)’ and ‘Destination: Working CMYK - Coated FOGRA39’, with profiles not included.

Crucially for this test, all spots are set to convert to process in the Ink Manager.

### Result…

Since the same colour profiles and synchronised Colour Settings are being used across the board, I would expect the colour values derived from 'Spots to Process' during InDesign’s export to PDF process to exactly match the colour values derived by converting the same Pantone colour to CMYK within InDesign itself.

Yet when I open the exported PDF in Acrobat and check the values using Print Production > Output Preview > Separations there is a discrepancy between the CMYK values of the colour converted during export and those of the colour converted via InDesign's colour palette at layout stage. It's not a big difference — a percentage point here or there — but it’s not zero.

I also note that the CMYK values for the unconverted Pantone swatch provided by InDesign’s Separations Preview palette (which show that ink as CMYK values because Ink Manager is telling it that all spots will be converted to process) match the ‘converted at export’ values seen in Acrobat, not the ‘converted within the colour palette prior to export’ values.

**So what’s going on here? Are there two different conversion algorithms in play?**

Comment: Best practice is conversion to CMYK in the RIP, not earlier

Comment: @MaxWyss, that's one out of several truths.

Comment: I just tested this and I can confirm that ~1% difference. I can't answer your question since I don't know *why* this rounding error occurs. It might just be a bug of some kind. Many of those small quirks in Adobe applications. My advice would be to stick to *one* way of doing the conversion. Either always keep Pantone colors as spot colors and convert on export or always convert them "manually" to CMYK in the swatch panel. I think I would choose the first.

Comment: Either way could be the "best". Defining brand colors as Pantone inks isn't really an especially unambiguous method as there are several ways of doing the conversion, and we can't really be sure about those provided Lab values.

Comment: I do indeed generally leave all PMS colours as Pantones in the artwork and convert upon export, as suggested. And there are very few instances where one might need to have a PMS ink and its process equivalent together in a document. Sometimes, however, Pantone ink and a process equivalent need to sit alongside each other. Eg. if the inside cover of a brochure is printed nicely in Pantones but the inner pages are printed as CMYK for budgetary reasons. One might find a CYMK conversion on the first inner page sitting across from a 'real' PMS on the inside cover. I'd like the best match possible.

Comment: I would also note that not all Pantone colours show a discrepancy between ‘colour palette’ conversion and ‘on export’ conversion. It depends on the Pantone colour in play.

Comment: Final comment (for now): my reason for getting into this at all is because I need to supply brand guideline documents, and need to provide RGB and CMYK equivalents of the brand colours. 

RGB is easy; I just convert via InDesign’s colour palette using an sRGB working space (since on-screen documents will never be viewed in a colour-calibrated monitor context and so, really, all bets are off). But for the CMYK values I need to provide the best numbers I can.

I think I'll settle on using the values from ID’s ‘Separations Preview‘ palette, since they seem to match the values after export.

Comment: @RickL, I just think there are so many uncertainties about those CMYK values that a 1% difference is the least of the problems. For a given Pantone ink we only have two Lab colors to rely on (coated/uncoated paper). Where does these values come from? Which paper did they print on and under which circumstances? In reality a Pantone ink is a *substance* - not a color. You buy the ink in a can and the quality isn't 100% uniform. Or you mix it yourself from other Pantone inks with some uncertainty. Then you apply the ink on some kind of paper at some density. Lots of room for variations here.

Comment: Besides that, if you provide CMYK values as brand colors, I hope you realize that these CMYK values will only be accurate when printed according to the ICC profile you converted to.

Comment: All the points above are true and valid, and my sincere thanks for those. But issues like paper stock and potential variation between profiles when printing slightly dodge the original question. Which is this: why should different tools within Adobe Creative Cloud produce different digital colour breakdowns from the same digital colour startpoint — BEFORE ink and paper are considered, and in a context where the colour profiles are the same between apps. Even if (given all the variables) those exported values are at the mercy of ink on paper, shouldn't they *at least* be consistent before that?

Comment: @RickL Yes, they should, but don't expect Adobe's programs to be perfect. Lots of bugs and inaccuracies persist for years.

Comment: @Wolff Indeed. Just today I discovered that somewhere in the last couple of updates Adobe Illustrator’s ‘Export for screens’ function has started exporting its JPEGs in the CMYK colour space. (At least, I *hope* that it’s a bug, because if it’s a deliberate change then it makes NO sense).